# How to minimize Ubuntu 16.04 bloated installation

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, usb-drive

I used Ubuntu 14.04 for a couple years and liked the experience. EXCEPT that it came with a ton of bloatware. And that bloatware constantly needed to be updated.

For example, I don't want nor need: music players, printer/scanner drivers, Thunderbird, or Bluetooth support. And I am *sick* of updating font packages. I don't care about your fonts.

I write code. I use Firefox.

Tonight I will be installing 16.04 (from a USB stick) on a new laptop. This will be a fresh start (not a dual boot). How can I install a more minimal version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I would not call all the preinstalled applications "bloatware", they're all useful for the majority of Ubuntu home users. And if you don't want them, you're free to remove them completely as you wish or to use a minimal Ubuntu installer that does not come with any optional apps at all.

Comment: @ByteCommander I've known hundreds of people who used Ubuntu at home or work, and not a single one used Thunderbird. My last laptop did not have Bluetooth hardware, but Ubuntu had several Bluetooth software packages. The problem is that I had nearly weekly updates for Thunderbird and Bluetooth. So the software was not just useless, but actively getting in my way. "Bloatware" is just a word, but I don't know of a better one. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install as normal then purge what you do not need. For example, the first thing I do on every Ubuntu installation is `sudo apt-get -y purge evolution-data-server` followed by `sudo apt-get -y --purge autoremove`. This gives me about 200 MiB more free memory...

The other variant is to go bottom up. Install Ubuntu Server, then

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

To see what is missing from the full desktop installation use

```
apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop | grep "Recommends"
```

Comment: I can do a post install purge.  Now that you say it, that sounds like a good way to go. It means I will have to learn more about what packages came with my distro, but I suppose I should really know that anyway. Good tip, I like it.

Comment: @theJollySin: The quick way to find which package owns a file is `dpkg-query -S /full/path/to/file`. To see what would be removed by removing a package use `sudo apt-get -s --autoremove package-name`.